# Spellchecking in Vim - tell Vim that this is okey

Tags: vim

*Yes, that title is the best I could come up with :-)*

I have a text, and when activating spellchecking naturally a lot of words come out highlighted. Like emails, adresses, names and so on. How to tell Vim that some word is okey, without adding it to the wordlist.

Meaning, just, while editing this document I don't want to see my name highlighted.

Comment: I never generally use the spellchecking feature, therefore my complete ignorance on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `zG`

```
:help internal-wordlist
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html

zg          Add word under the cursor as a good word to the first
            name in 'spellfile'.  A count may precede the command
            to indicate the entry in 'spellfile' to be used.  A
            count of two uses the second entry.

```
        In Visual mode the selected characters are added as a
        word (including white space!).
        When the cursor is on text that is marked as badly
        spelled then the marked text is used.
        Otherwise the word under the cursor, separated by
        non-word characters, is used.

        If the word is explicitly marked as bad word in
        another spell file the result is unpredictable.
```

Comment: I don't want to add any word (why would I want people's names in a wordlist?). I just want Vim to ignore it in this session.

Comment: I don't find it strange to add names, locations, etc. to the wordlist (especially if I use them often). Since they are independent of the language, I add them to a different, custom wordlist, which is active in all languages (English, German) that I edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have my Vim config in a git repository, which is useful for several things; For example, you could alias your `vim` to a small script that invokes Vim normally, but after Vim finishes checks if the `~/.vim/spell` directory has any modifications and if so, asks you if you want to keep or discard them. If you want to keep them, it could automatically commit everything in `spell` and otherwise reset everything in there. So you usually wont be bothered by that script unless you actually do use the spellchecker.

The only drawback would be that you couldn't both make persistent and volatile additions to the dictionary in one session.

Comment: Vim has this built-in, cp. the distinction between `zg` (permanent) and `zG` (session only).